# How to set imageview in Percent Relative Layout to following ratio's based on device screen size ,16:9,1:1,3:2,2:1,4:3

Tags: android, android-imageview, scale, aspect-ratio, android-constraintlayout

I have an imageview to display an image and i want to enable the option to crop the image using the following ratio's 16:9,1:1,3:2,2:1,4:3 .I have some buttons for each  ,so user can crop the image in to the following by clicking a button. How to do this based on devices with varying screen sizes.

I got the device screen height and width using the following code snippet

```
  DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
            int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

and i can set the width and height to imageview using this snippet

```
  FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.height=height;
            params.width=width;
            touchImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

But  how to do this with Percent Relative Layout (16:9,1:1,3:2,2:1,4:3)

can anyone help ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Percent Relative Layout

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

```
private void changeAspectRatio(int width, int height, Float ratio, PercentRelativeLayout mPercentRelativeLayout) {
    PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsMain = new PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams(getApplicationContext(), null);
    if (width != 0)
        layoutParamsMain.width = width;
    if (height != 0)
        layoutParamsMain.width = width;
    PercentLayoutHelper.PercentLayoutInfo info1 = layoutParamsMain.getPercentLayoutInfo();
    if (ratio != 0f)
        info1.aspectRatio = ratio;
    mPercentRelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsMain);
    mPercentRelativeLayout.requestLayout();
}


changeAspectRatio((int)(width*.9), 0, 1.77f, mPercentRelativeLayout);

to get 16:9 , 16/9 = 1.77 and pass this value like above function call.
```

Then it will set 16:9 aspect ratio.

Answer (score 4):

Since `PercentFrameLayout` and `PercentRelativeLayout` were deprecated in API level 26.0.0, I'd suggest you to consider using of `ConstraintLayout` to keep ratio 16:9 for your `ImageView`. `ConstraintLayout` is really powerful tool to build Responsive UI for Android platform, you can find more details here [Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html).

Here is the example how to build your ImageView into ConstraintLayout to keep 16:9 ratio:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,16:9"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Don't forget to add `constraint-layout` dependency to your module's `build.gradle` file

```
implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2"
```

---

Or instead of editing your XML file, edit your layout directly in Layout Editor:

[image: Layout Editor]